Get by reflection properties of class with private setters
I am trying to get all properties of a class that have a private setter. This seems very simple, however I run into a strange, but probably normal, behavior.
This is the solution I have implemented
public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> InstanceProperties(this Type type) {
    List<PropertyInfo> results = new();
    var allProperties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (var property in allProperties) {
        var setMethod = property.GetSetMethod(true);
        if (setMethod != null && setMethod.IsPrivate) {
            results.Add(property);
        }
    }
    return results;
}

I have created some simple classes for testing as well
public class BaseClass {
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public BaseClass(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public DerivedClass(string name, string description) : base(name) {
        Description = description;
    }
}

To test this I am using
[Fact]
public void InstanceProperties_WithBaseType_ReturnsAllProperties() {
    // Arrange
    Type baseEntityType = typeof(BaseClass);
    // Act
    var result = baseEntityType.InstanceProperties();
    // Assert
    result.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
    result.Count().Should().Be(1);
}

[Fact]
public void InstanceProperties_WithDerivedType_ReturnsAllProperties() {
    // Arrange
    Type baseEntityType = typeof(DerivedClass);
    // Act
    var result = baseEntityType.InstanceProperties();
    // Assert
    result.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
    result.Count().Should().Be(2);
}

The first test succeds while the second test fails. More specifically in second test, the code var allProperties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance); returns two properties however the property of the base class does not have a setter method. This is not properly coherent with the first test as in that case the property does have a set method which is defined as private.
Any suggestion/explanation about this behavior?
EDIT
As per suggestions from comments I better explain the scope of the question. The final objective is to constructs some types of objects that have the following characteristics:

Can be classes inheriting directly from a well known base class (e.g. Entity) which have a single unique instance property of type Guid with a private setter
Can be classes inheriting from an abstract base class that in turn inherits from Entity
All instance properties have a private setter
All classes have a single public static factory method called Create with, of course, different parameters for each class

I would like to understand how this construction technique is handled by Entity Framework which uses a private parameterless constructor to create object instances.
EDIT 2
I've ended up writing a solution which is very similar to the two presented by Jamiec and Gert Arnold. I am writing here for reference. Thanks everybody!
public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> InstanceProperties(this Type type) {
    List<PropertyInfo> results = new();
    Type? leafType = type;
    while (leafType != null) {
        var allProperties = leafType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (var property in allProperties) {
            var accessors = property
                .GetAccessors(true)
                .Where(a => a.ReturnType == typeof(void) && a.IsPrivate)
                .ToArray();
            foreach (var accessor in accessors) {
                results.Add(property);
            }
        }
        leafType = leafType.BaseType;
    }
    return results;
}


This is expected. Private members are not inherited. Do you want to assume you are in a fictional universe where private members are inherited? I doubt that would be useful. Perhaps this is a XY Problem?

Thanks for your answer. No, I don't believe this is an XY Problem. The final objective is to create a custom JsonConverter but I didn't want to focus on the JsonConverter as it is assured by documentation that STJ does not have the feature of deserializing objects with private setters. My objective is more related to create a behavior like EF does. In fact, Entity Framework is fully able to construct objects from database even when they have private setters and also when they inherits from a base entity with private setters.

Okay, how do you want to handle overrides? Suppose Name is virtual and instead of Description, DerivedClass declares public override string Name => "Foo";. How many properties should typeof(DerivedClass).InstanceProperties() return?

This is a well laid out question, but by definition it is an XY Problem. You ask about X (get private setter of a base class)  when what you really want is Y (construct an object by some means which is a derived class where some of the setters are private). You also have, in your derived class, constructor args which set those properties - why can't you use that to construct your object? What are you really trying to do?

@Sweeper: just one as it is overridden

@Jamiec: The objects which I am trying to construct cannot be changed. They can be normal classes or classes that inherits from an abstract base class. They all have private constructors but they all have a single static public method called Create. Of course, parameters of the Create method differs for each class. What I am trying to achieve is: (1) get the properties of the object to deserialize, (2) find the Create method and (3) based on the data in the json invoke dynamically the Create method

Ok, so now were getting to the real question. If you just want the names of the properties to pull from JSON, you shouldnt be caring if theyre private setters or not. You just need the name

Yes, you are correct on this. but having also other information about the property consent to implement a stronger convention during the creation of the object itself. I mean a convention which does not rely solely on the name of the property

Since you are writing a JsonConverter, expecting 1 property in this case is strange. Surely you would want it to return no properties at all, since the overridden implementation only has a getter that returns a constant value. You wouldn't expect there to be a "Name" in the JSON when deserialising DerivedClass, would you? As Jamiec said, this is most definitely an XY problem. Please [edit] your question to include the larger context. And think carefully about whether you want 0 or 1.

Can you clarify what "convention" means? Do you mean that it is a "convention" for properties that should be deserialised from JSON to have a private setter?

Just use BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Private | BindingFlags.Instance. N.B. private fields are (physically) inherited but are not visible in the derived class.

"All instance properties have a private setter", so why do you need to check the accessibility of the setter if you can assume this?

@Sweeper: I added edit while you were writing. With regards to connventions suppose that one class has this method public static DerivedClass Create(string name, string description). to invoke this method I need that parameter names are exactly equal to those present in the json string that I am parsing. During JSON deserialization however, also the type of the property can be useful and having also property types can helps to have a better matching

@OlivierJacot-Descombes: that easy? :D. However just to be precise it is BindingFlags.NonPublic. Let me try.

This could be as easy as a bit of recursion, if the type has a base type, also add those properties to your list:
public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> InstanceProperties(this Type type)
{
    List<PropertyInfo> results = new();
    var allProperties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (var property in allProperties)
    {
        var setMethod = property.GetSetMethod(true);
        if (setMethod != null && setMethod.IsPrivate)
        {
            results.Add(property);
        }
    }
    if(type.BaseType != null)
    {
        results.AddRange(type.BaseType.InstanceProperties());
    }
    return results;
}

This gives your expected output of 2 in this specific example, but might need some tweaking to match your exact expectation.

My final solution was very similar although I didn't use recursion as well as SetMethod. Wrote it in a final edit. Thanks a lot!

Use yield return and keep returning until the type doesn't have a base type:
public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> InstanceProperties(this Type type)
{
    while (type != null)
    {
        var allProperties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (var property in allProperties)
        {
            var setMethod = property.GetSetMethod(true);
            if (setMethod != null && setMethod.IsPrivate)
            {
                yield return property;
            }
        }
        type = type.BaseType;
    }
}


My final solution was very similar although I didn't use SetMethod anymore. Wrote it in a final edit for your reference. Thanks a lot!

Any reason to use GetAccessors? GetSetMethod gets the setter method directly without having to loop through both accessors. I know it's a micro optimization, but GetAccessors also makes the code more complex, for no obvious reason.

No specific reason. I tried with GetAccessors because by using BindingFlags.NonPublic to get private setters SonarCloud analysis started to complain with issues. The code does not loop however because there is a filter to get only setter. See Where(a => a.ReturnType == typeof(void) && a.IsPrivate). This is not optimised as could effectively change into a SingleOrDefault(). Definitely, it works both ways, still the code could be improved
